# Uninstalling the package... > Failed in Tizen Studio

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-studio, tizen-sdk

I am getting an issue "Uninstalling the package... > Fail" while going to run the application on TV, I can launch the application on TV if the same old app I remove manually. I have attached the error screenshot and TV information FYI.

- Tizen Studio Verion: 5.1
- SDK Version: 7.0
- TV S/N: UA43RU7100KXXL
- DUID: EXCA3YKLMP7CK

[image]

Comment: I have also tried to create new certificate but getting the same issue

Comment: You can try uninstalling manually through the TV Apps screen.